# How to count the Percentage of Yes/No Responses?

Tags: java, android, percentage

Please help,
I make a diagnosis app about bird disease. In this app any 29 question and just yes/no response. That response will finding the answer of bird disease. In this case i create 8 kind of bird disease.

Every "yes" response get value equal "1".

Every "no" response get value equal "0".

I want to make a count the Percentage of bird disease from Yes/No Responses, but i fail and feel confused.
example :

bird disease (1) 100%

bird disease (2) 45%

bird disease (3) 50%

bird disease (4) 0%

etc

[Image Gif my app diagnosis.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLVX.gif)

This my code Diagnosis.java

```
public class Diagnosa extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


int nomor, jumlah_jawaban = 0;
ArrayList<String> gejala, bobot, penyakit;
ArrayList<String> jawaban;
ArrayList<Double> persentase;

String debug;
View rootView;
TextView txtGejala, txtDebug, txt1;
Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6;

public static Diagnosa newInstance()
{
    return new Diagnosa();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diagnosa, container, false);


    nomor = 0;
    jawaban = new ArrayList<String>();
    persentase = new ArrayList<>();
    gejala = application.getGejala();
    bobot = application.getBobot();
    penyakit = application.getPenyakit();
    txt1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txtDebug = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtdebug);
    txtGejala = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtHasil);
    txtGejala.setText(gejala.get(nomor).toString());

    btn1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);


    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    txt1.setText("Silakan jawab pilihan gejala" + "\r\n" + "No. 1");

    return rootView;
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.btn1)
    {
        jawaban.add("1");
        jumlah_jawaban++;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.btn2)
    {
        jawaban.add("0");

    }

    nomor++;
    if (nomor < gejala.size())
    {
        txtGejala.setText(gejala.get(nomor).toString());
        txt1.setText("Silakan jawab pilihan gejala" + "\r\n" + "No. "+ String.valueOf(nomor+1));

    }
    else
    {
        try {
            hitungHasil();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Fragment fragment = Hasil.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();


    }
}

private void hitungHasil()
{

    debug = "";
    int nourut_jawaban = 0;
    int hasil = 100;

    try {

        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 1;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 2;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 3;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 4;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 5;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 6;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
            )
        {
            hasil = 7;
        }
        else
        if (
                jawaban.get(0).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(1).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(2).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(3).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(4).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(5).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(6).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(7).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(11).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(15).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(18).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                        && jawaban.get(27).equals("1")
                        && jawaban.get(28).equals("1")
                )
        {
            hasil = 8;
        }

        if (hasil > 0) {

        }
        else
        {
            hasil = 100;
        }

        application.setId(jumlah_jawaban);
        application.setStatus(String.valueOf(hasil - 1));


    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Diagnosa Selesai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you do is you count both yeses and noes.
Then you write:

```
int sum = yeses + noes;
float percentage = (float) yeses / (float) sum * 100.0f;
```

On a bit of a different note - I can't help but notice that copy-pasta in method `hitungHasil`. You shouldn't be doing that. Instead try something like this:

```
private boolean checkHitungHasil(String... values){
    for(int i=0; i<values.size; i++){
        if(!jawaban.get(i).equals(values[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then replace all that

```
    if (
            jawaban.get(0).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(1).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(2).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(3).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(4).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(5).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(6).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(7).equals("1")
                    && jawaban.get(8).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(9).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(10).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(11).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(12).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(13).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(14).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(15).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(16).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(17).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(18).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(19).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(20).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(21).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(22).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(23).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(24).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(25).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(26).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(27).equals("0")
                    && jawaban.get(28).equals("0")
        )
```

With:

```
if(checkHitungHasil("1","1","1","1","1","1","1",/*7th*/ "1",
/*8th*/"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"))
    ...
```

Comment: Float isn't float, and you probably meant "double" in the first place.

Comment: Still: dont use float, use double.

Comment: Why thou? Correct me if I'm wrong, but as a general rule - yes double is better, but in that specific instance there is nothing to gain from additional precision.

Comment: Basically because double is "the default". Like: when you write the literal 100.0, that is a **double** value. So you start of with a double multiplication. Then you cast to float, meaning you throw away precision after the fact. If you really want float, you could have done `sum * 100.0f` for example.

Comment: @Miku But there is also nothing to gain from explicitly casting to float.

Comment: All right - it is 100.0f now. But you still did not answer why it should be double. When talking about percentages we're rarely need more then 5 significant figures, so what's the point, especially when double is twice the size?

Comment: @MC Emperor Java when calculating values goes from left to right and casts when it's needed. At first it would see int divided by int, so it would produce 0 (unless there are no noes) and then multiply it by float. And 0 * 100.0f is 0.0f. Second cast is redundant, but the first one not.

Comment: @Miku Unless you change the operand order: `100.0 * yeses / sum`.

Comment: That's what I said. It goes from left to right and casts when it's needed. In that case there's double * int so the latter int is implicitly cast to double and the result is double.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing I am not allowed to add a comment yet (I don't have enough reputations so far), to build on Miku's answer: Be sure to check that `sum != 0`

To give you the full idea: I've adapted this from an app I made a while back:

```
private void updatePercentage() {
    String percentText;
    double base = yesClicks + noClicks;
    if (base != 0) {
        percentage = (yesClicks) / (base / 100);
        DecimalFormat percentageFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        percentText = percentageFormat.format(percentage) + "%";
    } else {
        percentage = 0;
        percentageText = "-"; //hardcoding here so you get the idea
    }
    percentage_textView.setText("-");
}
```